# If "i" is defined as an integer, how does it know if question==answers or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.7

This program is functional, my question is more for curiosity and education's sake. If I've defined "i" as the integers in the range of "answers"'s length, how is it that it knows whether the user's input is equal to the original strings or not?

Example:
(#first iteration) A, B, C, or D? (#I answer) B
(#answers[i]==1, but program knows it also equals B and verifies that the first input is correct. How does it know the first answers[i] is B if the "i"'s are defined as integers?

```
# List of question answers
answers = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D']

# List of user responses
response = []

# List of questions answered correctly
correct = []

# Number correctly answered
numCor = 0

# Number incorrectly answered
numIn = 0

# For every question answer, add user-reponse to response list
for i in range(len(answers)):
    question = input('A, B, C, or D: ')
    response.append(question)

    # If the user-response is equal to the question answer /
    # add 1 to correctly answered and add question-number to correct list
    if question == answers[i]:
        numCor += 1
        correct.append(i + 1)

    # If user-response does not match question answer /
    # add 1 to incorrectly answered
    else:
        numIn += 1

# Print correctly/incorrectly answered /
# and question-numbers answered correctly
print('You got', numCor, 'questions correct.')
print('You got', numIn, 'questions incorrect.')
print('Correct Questions:', correct)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`answers[i]` means you look up the i'th element in the `answers` array, and you get the value (a string in your case) that is stored there.

If you are in the first iteration,  `i` will be 0.

`answers[0]` will then give you the value stored at index 0 in `answers`, which is the string `'B'`

If the user inputs `B` , your comparison:

```
if question == answers[i]:
```

is the same as

```
if 'B' == 'B':
```